# Skype API help and acting very weird

Tags: api, skype

I've made a big app for Skype called (Skype PWN4G3) one of its features are these lines of code:

//Control's

```
 private void botOn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (toolStripLabel5.Text == "Not attached")
            {
                MessageBox.Show(notAttached, "Skype Pwnage - Info!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            else
            {
                botStop = false;
                skype.Attach(7, false);
                skype.MessageStatus += new _ISkypeEvents_MessageStatusEventHandler(skype_MessageStatus);
                botOn.Text = "Running";
                botOn.Enabled = false;
                botOff.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void botOff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            botStop = true;
            botOn.Text = "Enable";
            botOn.Enabled = true;
            botOff.Enabled = false;
        }
```

//Function

```
private void skype_MessageStatus(ChatMessage msg, TChatMessageStatus status)
{
    if (botStop == true)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            string command = msg.Body.Remove(0, trigger.Length).ToLower();
            string[] lines = richTextBox4.Text.Split('\n');
            foreach (string ln in lines)
            {
                string[] commands = ln.Split(':');
                if (radioButton6.Checked == true)
                {
                    if (command.Contains(commands[0]))
                    {
                        listBox2.Items.Add(DateTime.Now +"> "+ commands[0]);
                        skype.SendMessage(msg.Sender.Handle, string.Format(commands[1]));
                        break;
                    }
                }
                    if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
                    {
                        if (command == commands[0])
                        {
                            listBox2.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + "> " + commands[0]);
                            skype.SendMessage(msg.Sender.Handle, string.Format(commands[1]));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        catch (Exception err0)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

Now my issue is this code work's great and it will reply auto to a person if they say a certain word. But it's very odd acting.
If you start the bot with the Skype window minimized and let it do it's work it work's great until you stop then start it or change the radio button from "Exact" to "Contains" then the next time it runs it will reply 2 times, then if you do the above again it will reply 3 times and so on,

One other very odd problem is that once you open your Skype window and view the messages from your side it re-seneds them all again. Any idea why?

And one more extra if anyone know's how I can stop / start this correctly that would be fantastic. And if you know how to make it so this will not listen to messages from chat groups and only PM's that would be great because right now it will listen to chat then send to User.Handle unless I can make some way to have it send into chat where the message was sent.

Answer (score 1):

1) reply 2, 3 and more times - it seems that the problem is in `skype.MessageStatus += ...` that is being called each time you click on botOn. Either call `-=` or make sure that event subscription happens only once.

2) sending message again: skype_MessageStatus is being called for one message two times - check SKYPE4COMLib.TChatMessageStatus cmsSending/cmsReceived - when the message is delivered and cmsSent/cmsRead when target user clicks and actually views the message - so all you need to do is to check the value of `SKYPE4COMLib.TChatMessageStatus Status`

3) to make difference between direct messages and chat groups test in your code

```
SKYPE4COMLib.ChatMessage pMessage;
if (pMessage.Chat.Members.Count == 2)
{
    // process direct messages
}
else if(pMessage.Chat.Members.Count > 2)
{
    // do whatever you want to do to process chat messages
}
```